# Mecurial repository files lost - How do I recreate and push to the original cloned repo?

Tags: mercurial, repository, hgrc

I just lost my .hg* files for my repository after a migration and I have made a bunch of unpushed changes to some code.

I need to Init a new repository and then push my changes to an existing remote repository. Do I just need to init a new repo and then specify the remote repo in the hgrc and push? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remember the changeset you had in your original repo as its working parent (let's call it `A`), then you can do this:

```
$ hg clone http://server/upstream newrepo
$ cd newrepo
$ hg up A
```

Then copy the working copy of the original repo to the new repo (with an additional precaution of deleting all files from the new repo if you renamed / deleted anything in the old repo). Afterwards, commit and push from the new repo:

```
$ hg commit
$ hg push
```

If the upstream repo has anything on top of `A`, rebase or merge before pushing.